# Doing too many operation when creating csv files - Looking for help on optimization

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, unicode

I coded a small programm to download financial data, and divide it into csv with the second data, minute data, etc..., the programm is running fine, but I'm creating csv files that I delete later, and it seems like a waste of computing power, I was wondering if there were any ways to make it run quicker.

The programm looks like this:

```
url = 'https://tickdata.fxcorporate.com/EURUSD/2015/1.csv.gz'
urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, folder)
```

First I download a csv file from an url, this is the tick data that is necessary, however, this tick data has invalid symbols in it, so I need to correct it:

```
with gzip.open(folder, 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()

with gzip.open(file + '.csv.gz', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(data.decode('utf-8').replace('\x00', '').encode('utf-8'))
```

Here, I remove all the invalids `/x00` characters, so that python can read it fine (if I don't do that, I cannot handle the csv with pandas), thus creating another csv file.

Then, I do all the operation I need to create the several csv file with the data I need using pandas:

```
tick = pd.read_csv(file + '.csv.gz',compression='gzip')
tick.index = pd.to_datetime(tick['DateTime'],format="%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S.%f")
sec =  tick['Bid'].resample('1s').ohlc()
sec = sec.fillna(method="ffill")
sec.to_csv(file + '_S1.csv',float_format='%.5f')
...
```

And at the end, I remove the file I first created downloading the data, and the second one with the invalid characters removed:

```
os.remove(folder)
os.remove(file + '.csv.gz')
```

I'm not an expert, but it seems that creating two csv files and then deleting them is a waste of time, I didn't find any solutions to do less steps than I already do.

Would anyone have an idea of how to speed up the process by not writing the extra csv files?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give a sample URL so we can re-produce your results?

Comment: Why not just hold everything in memory ?

Comment: Python has `StringIO` (and it's faster C cousin `cStringIO`) which implement the buffer protocol expected by `panda.read_csv`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Download the file into memory rather than to disk. Try `urllib.request.urlopen` instead of `.urlretrieve`?
2. Decompress the data
3. Make the modification to fix the symbols, but don't write it back to disk.
4. Pass the resulting CSV text (not file) into a StringIO object, then pass the StringIO object to Pandas `read_csv`.

It might look something like this (in Python 3):

```
import pandas as pd
import urllib.request
import gzip
# Python3
from io import StringIO, BytesIO
# Python2
from cStringIO import StringIO  # I think, haven't done this in a while

compressed_data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read()
data = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=BytesIO(compressed_data)).read()
data = data.decode('utf-8').replace('\x00', '')
data = StringIO(data)
df = pd.read_csv(data)
```

Comment: Thanks, it looks like it would work perfectly for this, I tried it, and I got a `UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte` error message, I assume that it's linked to the fact that the data is in compressed and stored in a csv.gz, which wasn't an issue before because pandas could handle it.

The data that I'm downloading looks like that: https://tickdata.fxcorporate.com/EURUSD/2015/1.csv.gz

Comment: On it, give me a sec. Are you using Python 2 or 3?

Comment: Python 3, I used `from io import StringIO`

Comment: Alright, see the edited answer for how to decompress without hitting disk

Answer (score 0):

Your file is in `utf-16-le` encoding (Unicode 16 bit little endian).

You cannont just remove the `'\x00'` bytes. Instead you need to read the file or decode the data in the proper encoding:

```
data.decode('utf-16-le') # or maybe just utf-16le (I don't know Python)
```

To convert to `utf-8` you probably need this:

```
data.decode('utf-16-le').encode('utf-8')
```

---

Here is a hex dump of the first part of the file:

```
0000h: 44 00 61 00 74 00 65 00 54 00 69 00 6D 00 65 00  D.a.t.e.T.i.m.e. 
0010h: 2C 00 42 00 69 00 64 00 2C 00 41 00 73 00 6B 00  ,.B.i.d.,.A.s.k. 
0020h: 0D 00 0A 00 30 00 31 00 2F 00 30 00 34 00 2F 00  ....0.1./.0.4./. 
0030h: 32 00 30 00 31 00 35 00 20 00 32 00 32 00 3A 00  2.0.1.5. .2.2.:. 
0040h: 30 00 30 00 3A 00 30 00 30 00 2E 00 33 00 38 00  0.0.:.0.0...3.8. 
0050h: 39 00 2C 00 31 00 2E 00 31 00 39 00 35 00 34 00  9.,.1...1.9.5.4. 
0060h: 38 00 2C 00 31 00 2E 00 31 00 39 00 35 00 35 00  8.,.1...1.9.5.5. 
0070h: 37 00 0D 00 0A 00 30 00 31 00 2F 00 30 00 34 00  7.....0.1./.0.4. 
0080h: 2F 00 32 00 30 00 31 00 35 00 20 00 32 00 32 00  /.2.0.1.5. .2.2. 
0090h: 3A 00 30 00 30 00 3A 00 30 00 30 00 2E 00 34 00  :.0.0.:.0.0...4. 
00A0h: 30 00 36 00 2C 00 31 00 2E 00 31 00 39 00 35 00  0.6.,.1...1.9.5. 
00B0h: 34 00 34 00 2C 00 31 00 2E 00 31 00 39 00 35 00  4.4.,.1...1.9.5. 
00C0h: 35 00 36 00 0D 00 0A 00 30 00 31 00 2F 00 30 00  5.6.....0.1./.0. 
00D0h: 34 00 2F 00 32 00 30 00 31 00 35 00 20 00 32 00  4./.2.0.1.5. .2. 
00E0h: 32 00 3A 00 30 00 30 00 3A 00 30 00 30 00 2E 00  2.:.0.0.:.0.0... 
00F0h: 35 00 34 00 32 00 2C 00 31 00 2E 00 31 00 39 00  5.4.2.,.1...1.9. 
0100h: 35 00 33 00 39 00 2C 00 31 00 2E 00 31 00 39 00  5.3.9.,.1...1.9.
```

This clearly is `utf-16-le` encoding - each `char` is represented by 2 bytes. So the (only) right way to read that data is to read it as `utf-16-le`.

The reason it *seems* to work in `utf-8` mode is that all characters are lower ascii.

Also, reading as `utf-8` and removing the null bytes adds a lot of unnecessary overhead. Instead you can open the file in `utf-16-le` mode and keep the data in memory without the need for conversion.